# Как задать размер окна консольного приложения c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Как задать размер окна консольного c++ приложения?

Comment: Речь о том, чтобы программно менять размер консоли?

Answer (score 8):

Если программно, то надо установить размер буффера консоли.

Сначала получить хэндлк консоли с помощью GetStdHandle

А потом установить размер примерно так

```
HANDLE hWnd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
COORD bufferSize = {80, 50};
SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(wHnd, bufferSize);
```

Указав размер окна, остаётся изменить размер самого окна с помощью MoveWindow.

Answer (score 4):

```
system("mode con cols=80 lines=25");
```

Comment: Вы можете подробноее описать, что даст вызов system с предложеным параметром.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то вот так:

```
HWND hWindowConsole = GetConsoleWindow();
RECT r;
GetWindowRect(console, &r); //stores the console's current dimensions
MoveWindow(hWindowConsole, r.left, r.top, 400, 200, TRUE);
```