# Как изменить размер консоли в C++?

Tags: c++

Нужно с помощью кода C++ изменить размер консоли, но как именно это сделать не имею представления, в интернете нашёл что-то `system ("mode con cols=x lines=y");`Но не работает.

Comment: Я меняю так SetWindowPos(GetConsoleWindow(), NULL, m_pos.x, m_pos.y, sizeX, sizeY, NULL)

Comment: #helldrg вместо sizeX и sizeY надо подставить свои значения?

Comment: да и всесто m_pos

Comment: @helldrg - что-то на MaсOS не работает...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov печально, предложите свой вариант

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если программно, то надо установить размер буффера консоли.

Сначала получить хэндлк консоли с помощью `GetStdHandle`

А потом установить размер примерно так

```
HANDLE hWnd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
COORD bufferSize = {80, 50};
SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(wHnd, bufferSize);
```

Указав размер окна, остаётся изменить размер самого окна с помощью MoveWindow.
[оригинал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/41334)

Comment: Кхм... На Линуксе сработает?